# PDF of circularly symmetric matrix variate normal distribution

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution, multilinear-algebra

I am reading a paper and got stuck on a formula stated without elaboration.

The formula stated that for a model:

$$X=\sqrt \rho SH+W$$

with $S$ is random complex $T\times M$.

$H$ is random complex $M\times N$ having elements i.i.d and circular symmetric normal $CN(0,1)$.

and $W$ is random complex $T\times N$ having elements i.i.d and $CN(0,1)$.

The paper states that given $S$, $X$ is conditional complex normal with PDF:
$$f(X|S)=(1/\pi)^{NT} \times \frac{\exp{[tr(X^+(\rho SS^+ + I)^{-1}X)]}}{(\det(\rho X X^+ + I))^N}$$

with $tr$ means trace of matrix, and $^+$ is conjungate transpose.

I am trying to prove this formula without success.

I use the general matrix normal distribution that can be found here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution
for a zero mean $X$

Given $S$, with notation $\Bbb{E}$ for expectance, $\Re$ is real(.), $\Im$ is imag(.). If $X=A+jB$,

set $Y=\begin{bmatrix}
        A \\
        B \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

$\Gamma = \Bbb{E}[XX^+|S]=\rho SS^+ + I$

$C = \Bbb{E}[XX^T] = 0$ (circularly symmetric)

$\Gamma_T = \Bbb{E}[X^+X]=\rho\Bbb{E}[H^+ SS^+H] + I$

$C_T = \Bbb{E}[X^TX] = 0$ (circularly symmetric)

Because $C=0$ and $C_T=0$, we have

$\Bbb{E}[AA^T] = 0.5 \times \Re(\Gamma)$

$\Bbb{E}[AB^T] = 0.5 \times \Im(-\Gamma)$

$\Bbb{E}[BA^T] = 0.5 \times \Im(\Gamma)$

$\Bbb{E}[BB^T] = 0.5 \times \Re(\Gamma)$

$\Bbb{E}[A^TA] = \Bbb{E}[B^TB] = 0.5 \times \Re(\Gamma_T)$

Then

$U \times tr(V)=\Bbb{E}[YY^T|S]=0.5 \times
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \Re(\Gamma) & -\Im(\Gamma) \\
        \Im(\Gamma) & \Re(\Gamma) \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

$V \times tr(U)=\Bbb{E}[Y^TY|S]=\Re(\Gamma_T)$

**Then**
$U^{-1} = 2\times tr(V) 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Re(\Gamma^{-1}) & -\Im(\Gamma^{-1}) \\
\Im(\Gamma^{-1}) & \Re(\Gamma^{-1}) \\
\end{bmatrix}$

With simple manipulation

$Y^TU^{-1}Y = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A^T & B^T
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Re(\Gamma^{-1}) & -\Im(\Gamma^{-1}) \\
\Im(\Gamma^{-1}) & \Re(\Gamma^{-1}) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A^T \\ B^T\\
\end{bmatrix}$

$X^+\Gamma^{-1}X = (A^T-jB^T)(\Re(\Gamma^{-1})+j\Im(\Gamma^{-1}))(A+jB)=(2tr(V))^{-1} \times Y^TU^{-1}Y + j(..)$

Consider only the case ***that $X^+\Gamma^{-1}X$ is real*** (a classic assumption), $2tr(V)\times X^+\Gamma^{-1}X = Y^TU^{-1}Y$

The inner part of exp in denominator of the PDF becomes

$-0.5tr(V^{-1}Y^TU^{-1}Y)=-tr(V)tr(V^{-1}X^+\Gamma^{-1}X)$

In comparing with the stated formula

$-tr(X^+\Gamma^{-1}X)$

I got stuck here. It seems that the V matrix part vanishes in the stated formula but I don't know how. I tried using the zero pseudo-covariance characteristic of circular symmetric variable but no success.
Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The paper is **Multiple-Antennas and Isotropically Random Unitary Inputs: The Received Signal Density in Closed Form**. The formula can be found at the beginning of section II.A.